# PHP is not updating the current time inside while loop

Tags: php

Am trying to get current time and show it in the console using PHP CLI script. The problem is, am unable to get current time updated inside a while loop that runs infinitely but sleeps every second. Whatever the time I get when the program starts, will stick till the program ends.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

while(1) {
    $ts = new DateTime();
    $ts->getTimestamp();
    $now_ts = $ts->format("H:m:i");
    echo "\n{$now_ts}";

    sleep(1);
}
```

Am not able to understand what is happening here. Please help.

Comment: `H:m:i` is the format for Hours:month:minute - are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @iainn Not really. I understood what I was doing :) Now correctly using `H:i:s` - Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ts->format("H:m:i");
```

should be

```
$ts->format("H:i:s");
```

Because `i` represents minutes.

`m` is the numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Ooops! I really need to get some sleep. Thank you so much for pointing out.